# Change bootstrap column order on different resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Boostrap and this is my html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">B</div>
</div>
```

This is what appears in front-end:

A   | B

This is what obviously appears on mobile screen:

A

B

How can I change my code to have this?

B

A

---

**

### SOLVED

**

I solved in this way. Please let me know if my solution is wrong even if it works:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-right col-sm-push-7">B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-left col-sm-pull-5">A</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't in smaller screens. But if you want a solution with flexbox I will be happy to provide one

Comment: fortunately I founded a bootstrap solution. thanks the same bro!!

Comment: Depending on what browsers you need to support, you might want to look at `display:flex; flex-direction: column-reverse` or `display:flex; flex-direction: column;` + `order:N` on child.

Answer (score 0):

For web view you can set `B` before `A` and use `fload: right;` in css or `pull-right` class. Like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 pull-right">B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">A</div>
</div>
```